# Text get trimmed even if there is more than enough space on some devices

Tags: ios, swiftui

On some devices (like iPhone 8+ and iPhone 11 Pro Max) my text inside a Text element is getting trimmed even if there is enough space left. I have placed my Text like this:

```
HStack {
        Spacer()
        
        Text(result.number)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(12)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        
        Spacer()
}
```

But even a small text like "00000000" is getting trimmed way too early. What makes me wonder is, that the very same text works fine on a smaller device like the iPhone 11 or SE. For me it looks like that the Spacer take way more space as it should. So whats wrong here?

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzWyJ.png)

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 11.4 and Xcode 12.

Comment: @Asperi did you use the iPhone 8+ or iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator? Because it only happens there for me. In every other device and simulator it works fine. I can recreate this in Xcode 11.4 and Xcode 12.

Comment: Yes, I used those devices on simulator as mentioned. Would you provide complete reproducible code example?

Comment: @Asperi thanks for your help offers. I found a solution today, at least I think so. I removed the HStack completly and use .multilineTextAlignment(.center) now.